# HTML5 number input step bug

Tags: html, input

I am trying to use the new HTML5 number input for users to input a price.  I want the step to be "0.01".  This should be fairly simple, and my code looks like this:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" />
```

Well if you click on the arrows a bit, you'll get numbers like `1.1400000000000001` or numbers like `1.1` which both don't make sense for dollars.

Does anyone know of a way to make the number field actually step by 0.01, and to have a consistent number of significant figures?  Or if anyone has a more elegant solution for allowing users to input prices, I would love to hear it.

Thanks

Comment: Short answer -- don't use floating-point for money. Use pennies; but not sure the number control will give you 0.00 formatting for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all expecting Html 5 stuff to work as expected so early in the game and designing applications around that is probably not such a good idea.

As for a solution, yes just to JavaScript to increment and provide the user to up/down arrows or whatever and the click event could simple increment/decrement the value by the step value you desire.

Answer (score 0):

this is the expected javascript behavior, you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15100470/536984)