# Mongoose increment value wrong after a few times

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Ive got a collection Products in MongoDB. An app running Express 3 and Mongoose. I'm doing auctions and when I try to increment the price of a product by 0.01, it works fine until the 6th time, then goes to "1000.0699999999999" instead of 1000.07. Any idea why? After another few clicks it will be: 1000.1699999999998 and so on.

Here my update function:

```
app.post('/auctions/add', function(req, res){

  //Get username
  var user = req.session.username ;

  //Product ID from form
  var productID = req.body.product_id ;

  //Find and update product
  //Products.update( { id: productID }, { price: this.price + 0.01 } ).exec() ;
  Products.update( { id: productID }, {$inc: { price: .01 }, user_bidding: { username: user, timeBid: new Date() }}, function(err, numberAffected, raw) {

    console.log(err);
    console.log(numberAffected);
    console.log(raw);

  } ) ;

  //redirect to home
  res.redirect( '/' );

}) ;
```

Comment: It's because you're using a `double` to store the price, and doubles are often just approximations.  Store your price as an integer count of cents instead.

Comment: yes, i had this same problem. Ended up storing the cents. That's what we did at PayPal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not a mongoose problem.. this is how javascript works... in javascript `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3`.. this is because floating point arithmetic is not exact (or at least is not what you expect).. but integer arithmetic in floating point operation is exact.. you can convert the values to integers, make the sum, and then divide to leave everything as it was..

example.

`(0.1 * 10 + 0.2 * 10)/10 === 0.3`

so in your case something like

```
var price = 1000; 
price = (price*100 + 0.01*100)/100 // => 1000.01;
```

**EDIT:**

btw the suggestions to work in cents is really better.. you should take that into account

Answer (score 0):

I think price.toFixed(3) is better solution. No cents, no period.

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: Error by floating point format is a negligible. As you use toFixed you round value to lose sight of this. This is idea of floating point format. You have to add at least 9999999999 by 0.01 to have error of 0.01. This way conversion  toFixed solve a problem.

Comment: Also,if you meaning to make a LOT of operatios, you can use JavaScript library for arbitrary-precision decimal arithmetic.